# Android - Query String instead of integer

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to query a string (TEXT field in the database) and want to fetch records based on that query. I was following a tutorial which works fine if I query an Integer (the _ID field). What will I need to change in the code below to let it search for the string (the TEXT field) instead of the _ID field?

The activity code:

```
protected void getDetails() {
    try
    {
        // The ArrayList that holds the row data
        ArrayList<Object> row;
        // ask the database manager to retrieve the row with the given rowID
        row = db.getRowAsArray(Long.parseLong(txtProjContacts.getText().toString()));

        // update the form fields to hold the retrieved data
        txtName.setText((String)row.get(1));
        txtEmail.setText((String)row.get(2));
        txtExpertise.setText((String)row.get(3));
        txtCharges.setText((String)row.get(4));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Retrieve Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The DB Adapter code:

```
public ArrayList<Object> getRowAsArray(Long rowID)
{
    // create an array list to store data from the database row.
    // I would recommend creating a JavaBean compliant object 
    // to store this data instead.  That way you can ensure
    // data types are correct.
    ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Cursor cursor;

    try
    {
        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object store the information collected from the
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        cursor = db.query
        (
                TABLE_CONTACTS,
                new String[] {     TABLE_CON_ID,
                                TABLE_CON_NAME,
                                TABLE_CON_EMAIL,
                                TABLE_CON_EXPERTISE,
                                TABLE_CON_CHARGES},
                TABLE_CON_ID + "=" + rowID,
                null, null, null, null, null
        );

        // move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
        // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(4));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return the ArrayList containing the given row from the database.
    return rowArray;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you're select condition is such that it's enclosed within quotes.

**Untested Code**

```
cursor = db.query
        (
                TABLE_CONTACTS,
                new String[] {     TABLE_CON_ID,
                                TABLE_CON_NAME,
                                TABLE_CON_EMAIL,
                                TABLE_CON_EXPERTISE,
                                TABLE_CON_CHARGES},
                TABLE_CON_NAME + "= \"" + name_to_be_searched + "\"",
                null, null, null, null, null
        );
```

But this leads to the Possibility of SQL Injection so use [SQLLiteQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQuery.html)

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot st0le. A lifesaver indeed. :)